# Lumen 5.5 Send a default parameter in each json response

Tags: json, laravel, response, middleware, lumen

I am looking for a way to send an additional parameter in each JSON response to send the user current subscription status.

I am checking the subscription status in `App\Http\Middleware` which checks the user subscription status and process the request, would be great if I can send the global parameter from the middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **After Middleware** to do this.

**After Middleware** is run ***after*** a controller method has been called, meaning you can modify the response (adding your key) just before it is sent to the browser.

For example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AddSubscription
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $data = $response->getData();
        $data['subscription'] = getSubscriptionData(); // Put your subscription data here
        $response->setData($data);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

See the docs: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware (scroll to **Before / After Middleware**)

Comment: Superb! Thanks for this.

Comment: Hello @jamesking56, I am getting `undefined function getData` in case when there is a syntax error in my code and laravel return a html response showing the error. Could you suggest me how to handle this as if I use `isset($response->getData())` it throws `cannot use isset on a expression`.

Comment: @Puneee please make a new Stack Overflow post showing the code with the error.

Answer (score 1):

you can use append in the model and set mutation to that parameter like this

```
protected $appends = ['subscribed'];

public function getSubscribedAttrubite() {
  // you login of checking the the subscriber has subscription 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the application has 10 different models and will have more in future so I don't think this is the right way to implement this. I am looking for a global solution for the complete application.

Comment: you can add this to a trait and use it in all models that you want to extend from it

Comment: I have a wokring solution, will anwser when I'm home

Comment: I cannot use models for each response, sometimes there are more than one model I produce payload from.

Answer (score 1):

what if you add this to a main controller which other controllers extend from

```
public function respondJson($message,$status,$statusCode=200,$headers=[])
{
    return response()->json([
          'data'=>[
                    message'=>$message,
                   'subscriptionStatus'=>$status
                  ]
           ],$statusCode,$headers);
}
```

And in your controllers you call it like

```
$this->respondJson('some message',$status);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mahdi, this is useful but not the complete solution as I have to change 100s of controller functions to implement this.